# Highcharts how to remove headers from tooltip

Tags: highcharts

[image]

How to remove the 0 above Kosten?
I suppose I should add something to series to hide it.

[My highcharts script](http://pastebin.com/pH9VrBf6)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will have to look into the tooltip options:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip

I added the following bit of code that removed the numbers above `kosten`

```
tooltip:{
         headerFormat: '',
},
```

It basically replaces the values from the x axis (0,1,2, etc) in the tooltip with an empty string, therefore it doesn`t appear.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4pp1zhfb/5/

Comment: That solution is not working on split mode unfortunately...... box is shown, just empty. Any solution for that ?

Comment: I think it might be better to open a new issue and show the code that you currently have